# How to make a 2D sprite rotate towards a specific point while facing perpendicular to the camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

So I am creating a 2D project. I want my 2D sprite (a worm) to rotate in the direction of a specific point (eg a football sprite) in my game plane. I tried using `LookRotation` but the problem is the worm is not facing perpendicular to the camera so it is not visible in 2D view. My game is on the X/Y plane.

It looks like this when I run it;
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBGFp.png) (Notice that the worm is not visible?)

This is the 3D view;
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q76sa.png)

And this is the code;

```
Vector3 relativePos = target.transform.position - worm.transform.position;
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (relativePos);   
worm.transform.rotation = rotation;
```

Also, changing the upward direction, like setting it to `vector3.forward` is not working. Many thanks.

Comment: You should group together all of the planar game elements, and just rotate the entire group the face the camera, while treating the elements as 2D by suppressing one of the coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just wan't to rotate the worm alone to face the target I will assume that you only want it to rotate in the Z axis. I copied your code, changed it to only follow the Z axis and it kinda looks at the target. I don't if this is the behaviour you want but if it is here is the code.

```
Vector3 relativePos = target.transform.position - worm.transform.position;
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos);
rotation.x = worm.transform.rotation.x;
rotation.y = worm.transform.rotation.y;
worm.transform.rotation = rotation;
```

Here is an example of the behaviour with a cube facing a ball.

[image: E1]

[image: E2]

[image: E3]

Comment: Thanks , this was exactly what I wanted . It was so simple and I wandered for days to find an answer .

Comment: If it solved you problem could you please mark as answered :) @JoeBrar

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem when I was doing game development in unity. You CANNOT use a 3d Vector to accomplish this. This is because it will turn to face the player the worm will turn 90 degrees essentially making it cut through the scene.

Here is the code that I usually use for a top down game:

```
 var dir = WorldPos - transform.position;
 var angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
 transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
```

EDIT:
I forgot to mention this but `WorldPos` is from ScreenToWorldPoint